# Connecting SSMS ver 18.2 to SQL Server 2019 preview

Tags: sql-server

Cannot connect to SQL Server 2019 preview on Ubuntu through SSMS ver 18.2. Can anyone shed some light on this or has anyone had the same problem?

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server '192.168.0.30'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18142.0+((SSMS_Rel).190722-0816)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The database 'sms' cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 869 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database 'sms'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL  Server, Error: 948)

or when trying to connect SSMS to SQL Server 2019

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to 192.168.0.20.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

Here are the known issues for SSMS under Linux:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-2017#known-issues

If no issue matches, you could try to connect the server with [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017#get-azure-data-studio-for-linux) and see whether the same problem persists.

I would suggest to use [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017#get-azure-data-studio-for-linux) under Linux if it is sufficient for your needs.